# Read from one channel and write to another within one select-case

Tags: go, channel

Consider this Go code which shall call `worker.DoWork()` immediately and then once every minute:

```golang
triggerChan := make(chan time.Time, 1)
triggerChan <- time.Now() // We don't want to wait a minute for the first call of worker.DoWork() to happen.
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute)
defer ticker.Stop()
for {
    select {
    case triggerChan <- <-ticker.C:
    case <-triggerChan:
        worker.DoWork()
    }
}
```

A value is written to `triggerChan` before the first `select` to direct it into `case <-triggerChan` to have `worker.DoWork()` called immediately. However, in the case that `ticker.C` already had a value available (not all that unlikely if we used something like `time.Microsecond` instead of `time.Minute`), what would happen? Would the runtime see that `triggerChan <- <-ticker.C` would block, or would it happily soft-lock unaware of what is trying to be done with the result of `<-ticker.C`? Is it aware of this "from channel into channel"-situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [select with channel <- <- channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615326/select-with-channel-channel/35615600#35615600)

Comment: Because the expression `<-ticker.C` is evaluated on entry to the select, no work is done until the first tick.

Comment: @PenelopeStevens There's an ample foundation for some serious overengineering here. I did what you recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` decides based on the state of `triggerChan`, however it first evaluates the right hand side expressions for send operations.
So on entry, it will wait until <-ticker.C returns. Then it will read the first value from the channel, and then write to it...